# How can I modify a list property from a custom action using the client object model?

Tags: custom-actions, elements-xml

My task is to process selected items of some list. Can I change some field value from the client object model ?

I found some solution like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">



<CustomAction

Id="CAAlertRibbonButton"
RegistrationId="100"
RegistrationType="List"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
Sequence="5"
Title="Alert Ribbon Button">

<CommandUIExtension>
<CommandUIDefinitions>
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.Settings.Controls._children">
<Button
Id="AlertRibbonButtonId"
Alt="Alert Ribbon Button"
Sequence="5"
Command="CMDAlertRibbonButton"
Image32by32="/_layouts/images/menulistsettings.gif"
Image16by16="/_layouts/images/itdcl.gif"
LabelText="Alert Ribbon Button"
TemplateAlias="o1" />
</CommandUIDefinition>
</CommandUIDefinitions>

<CommandUIHandlers>
<CommandUIHandler
Command="CMDAlertRibbonButton"
CommandAction="javascript:
function resultCallback(result, value)
 {
 SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Success!');
 SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
 }

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
var myItems = '';
var i;

for (i in items)
{
myItems += '|' + items[i].id;
}

if(myItems != '')
 {
    // **I need call SERVER CODE here!**
 }" />
</CommandUIHandlers>

</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

and.. How can i call server code there?
And one more question.. I need to place this button in manage elements section. How can i do this?

Comment: Please just ask one question. If you have another question please create a new one.

Comment: if I write < in the ScriptLink, this is not legal in XML.
Also I always have the problem, that in a Custom Action there is no web. Have you tested your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use somethig like this code in client object model for item property update

```
function UpdateSelectedItemProperty(internalFieldName, propertyValue) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var selectedListId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(selectedListId);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        if (selectedItems[i].fsObjType == 0) {
            var listItem = list.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            context.load(listItem);
            listItem.set_item(internalFieldName, propertyValue);
            listItem.update();
        }
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(UpdateItemsSucceeded, UpdateItemsFailed);
}

function UpdateItemsSucceeded() {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}

function UpdateItemsFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Could not update items');
}
```

to place action to the manage elements section use this definition

```
<CustomAction Id="id"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
                RegistrationId="100"
                RegistrationType="List"
                Title="title">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.Controls._children">
```